Err:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/appimagelauncher-team/stable/ubuntu oracular Release 404 Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.80 443]
Can anyone help with the following when doing a sudo apt update?
Hit:1 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oracular InRelease
Hit:2 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oracular-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oracular-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oracular-security InRelease
Ign:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/appimagelauncher-team/stable/ubuntu oracular InRelease
Err:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/appimagelauncher-team/stable/ubuntu oracular Release
404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.80 443]
Error: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/appimagelauncher-team/stable/ubuntu oracular Release' does not have a Release file.
Notice: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
Notice: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

PPAs or Personal Package Archives are 3rd party sources; and the creator/owner/maintainer of the PPA or personal archive gets to choose what releases they support. Taken from your details is https://launchpad.net/~appimagelauncher-team/+archive/ubuntu/stable which clearly shows the owner stopped supporting this PPA back in 2022 or 112 weeks ago; it has no support beyond 22.10, so why was it added? You should check to see you're not importing problems before adding; you need to remove it now, as your addition of it is a problem.
